# Probability Density Estimation vs Function Approximation

Tags: nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation, online-algorithms

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ and I would like to estimate it. The data pairs $\{(x_i, f(x_i))\}$ arrive at different times $t$. I have two questions:

1. In this case, since the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}_+$ is density estimation the same as function approximation?
2. What techniques are available to approximate $f$ sequentially? I know GPs are an option but they are super expensive and probably an overkill for a 1D problem. Maybe some Gaussian Mixture Regression? I tried looking at the literature but I can't find anything that has an implementation in say python or julia.

Importantly, is this non-linear regression? What is this task called? I am so confused.

Comment: Just to clarify data arrives like this:

- At time $t=1$ we get $x_1$ and compute $f(x_1)$. 
- At time $t=\tau$ we get $x_\tau$ and would like to **UPDATE** my previous function approximation $\hat{f}_{\tau-1}$ to $\hat{f}_\tau$ by using $(x_\tau, f(x_\tau))$

Comment: To _estimate_ a real number or a function, the minimal requirement is a probabilistic framework. (And a positive valued function is usually _not_ a density function. It may even have an infinite mass.)